# Installing SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard/Enterprise when Express is installed

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-express

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with advanced services installed on my computer. I tried creating an SSIS package today and found out that the express edition does not support it.

Can I install Standard/Enterprise and have Express and Standard/Enterprise live happily on my development machine or do I need to uninstall Express?

Thanks

Comment: You can have any number of SQL Server instances on a single machine - you just need separate instance names. SQL Server Express is typically installed as instance `SQLExpress` - so any other name (including an empty name for the default instance) should be just fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You can either install a new instance so you have both a Express and Standard instance on the machine; or you can upgrade your Express instance to Standard/Enterprise. If the option to upgrade the SKU is not visible in setup then run setup.exe with `SKUUPGRADE=1` on the command line.